# Characters getting dropped when read from file?

Tags: java, unicode

Folks,

I have a some non-ASCII input that I need to parse using delimiters.  If I open the input file in TextPad binary mode, I can see the delimiter is actually a 3-character sequence of hex values C3, 83, and 3F.  That middle character (the "no break here" control character) is giving me grief.  When I read the file into a string in java, that character seems to be stripped away.

Example code (there is only 1 line in the file:)

```
String escapedDelimiter = args[0];
String delimiter = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(escapedDelimiter);
String s = null;

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(args[1]), Charset.forName(args[2])))) {
    s = br.readLine();
}

System.out.println(delimiter);
System.out.println("delimiter length: " + delimiter.length());
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println("s length: " + s.length());

int i = s.indexOf(delimiter);
System.out.println(i);
```

Output:

> Ã?
>
> delimiter length: 3
>
> Ã?HelloÃ?WorldÃ?
>
> s length: 16
>
> -1

Delimiter length is correct but s length is not.  The file contains 19 bytes.  One character from each of the 3 delimiters is missing.

Hard-coding the string like this works, but I need to read the input from a file:

```
String s = "\u00C3\u0083\u003FHelloÃ\u0083?World";
```

Interestingly, after typing in the first 3 escaped characters, copying and pasting them after "Hello" caused them to be replaced by the Ã\u0083?.  It's that middle character that is causing trouble.

Anybody know what's going on?

thanks

Comment: Well which encoding are you trying? My guess is that it's not the right encoding for the file...

Comment: If the file is in UTF-8, then that delimiter is *2* characters long, not 3. "Ã?" is the UTF-8-decoded version of 0xc3 0x83 0x3f. That's a pretty odd delimiter though...

Comment: "?" is sometimes used to silently drop data ([replacement character strategy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#decode-java.nio.ByteBuffer-)) when text is read with an encoding that it wasn't written with. The default behavior depends on the platform and actual behavior depends on the coding. If "?" looks wrong here, it could be that the input file has already been corrupted by an upstream process. In any case, you have to look upstream to know the character encoding to use to read any text file.

Comment: Just want to emphasize what Tom said. This file has been corrupted "upstream" by using the wrong character decoder. Fix that, restate your question if you still have one.

Answer (score 0):

I would read the file as a byte array instead, looking for the exact delimiter you want.  Then convert the byte[] to a String.

If performance/memory usage isn't an issue, I'd use Commons IO to read the bytes.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToByteArray(java.io.File)

Then search the array for the pattern you want.  Finally, convert the other chunks to a String.

```
String value = new String(myBytes) ;
```

If you are worried about performance/memory, read the bytes linearly using:

```
(byte) InputStream.read()
```

Searching for your delimiters as you proceed.

Comment: This seems like a fine strategy but `new String(myBytes)` will use a different character encoding across systems, users, and time—seldom what's wanted.

Comment: @TomBlodget gives great advice.  Make sure you use the String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset) constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(args[1]), Charset.forName(args[2]))` replace `Charset.forName(args[2])` with hardcoded `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`, see if it helps. Also reading it as bytes and working as bytes may help. There is another tool that may help you - I wrote a Utility that converts any String into Unicode sequences and vise-versa. Playng with wierd cases like this and converting it back and force sometimes may help you to understand the issue. Here is the link to an article that explains where to get the Open source library and how to use it: [Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman). Look for paragraph "**String Unicode converter**"